# Validate Hardcoded Password

Tags: android, kotlin, validation, passwords, equals

I am using Kotlin.

I have a stored password (val password = 1111). I have an editText (passcode) that takes a "numberPassword" input. I would like the user to input the code and if it matches I will do something.

I have tried:

`if (passcode.equals(1111)) { //do something }`

`if (passcode = password) { //do something }`

`if (passcode.text.toString() == password) { //do something }`

`if (passcode == "1111") { //do something }`

...
and many other versions switching back and forth from int to string

This should be very simple since the user is either right or wrong. I am guessing it has to do with string/int stuff. Thanks for your help!

Just Tried:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passcode"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="@string/zeros"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_key"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/light_gray"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autofillHints="true" />
```

`private var passcode: EditText? = null private var password: Int = 1111`

```
        view.submitButton?.setOnClickListener {
          
            if (passcode?.text.toString() == password.toString()){


                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreen, "Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@SplashScreen, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               
            }
        }
```

Result: Invalid when I enter 1111 in edittext

Comment: The only thing that is incorrect is that the 'passcode' variable is still null, you want to set it to the view instance, passcode should equal 'findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passcode)' then it should work

Comment: I have that, just didn't include it. I put the View instance in a separate area. Any other ideas?

Comment: Everything is ok with your code if you have findViewById. Stupid solution, but try to invalidate and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I figured it out. I failed to inform that this was inside a dialog popup. I added my view instance inside the submitButton and it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password variable is not initialized as it is still null.

Set it like this:

```
private var passcode : EditText? = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passcode)
```

Comment: I implemented what you said. It is still not validating. I will add more details to my question

Comment: It is generating a compile error, runtime error, or a crash? Could you include all of your code in your question for me?

Comment: just did. No errors, just says invalid instead of valid

Comment: Read my new comment on your question

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the whole widget to the variable password.
What you need is to compare the password variable with `passcode.text.toString()`
like this:

```
 if (passcode.text.toString() == password.toString()){
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Correct Passcode!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Wrong Passcode!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you referenced the EditText Widget? I tried it as passcode?. / passcode. and both of them worked.

Comment: yes, I have "passcode = findViewById(R.id.passcode)" in my onCreate

Comment: I figured it out. I failed to inform that this was inside a dialog popup. I added my view instance inside the submitButton and it works now.

Comment: Happy to hear that, Goodluck with your app!